# How to receive data in wordpress from external web service

Tags: wordpress, laravel, rest, api

I have some URL's in JSON format from  a Laravel Application.  Can anyone give Some example how to receive those data.

Comment: If I understand it right, you need to make eg. GET request and you will get json as response, right? For making get request you can use [this helper function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get).

Answer (score 1):

From a WordPress perspective, you should look at the HTTP API methods:

https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

This method will allow you to easily retrieve data from the restful API.
For instance, assuming that you are using the JSON API, you can use something like this:

```
$api_request    = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US...';
$api_response = wp_remote_get( $api_request );
$api_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_response ), true );
```

In this example, `$api_data` will be a stdClass object containing all the information returned by the API.